# Flutter Navigator.of(context).pop() in showDialog, close full app in ios

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

i have a problem in the ios version of my app, this is the code.

```
void showErrorAlert(BuildContext context, String msj) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error'),
        content: Text(msj),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Text('ok'),
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

the Navigator.of(context).pop() in android works perfect, close the dialog and everything is ok, but in ios, the full app is closed when that code is called 'Navigator.of(context).pop()', someone know what can i do to close only the dialog in ios?

P.D.: i dont have any error or warning in the output console, even when te app get closed
P.D.2: i already tried change the .pop to this 'Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog')' but it doesnt work

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: Sry, it was ' i dont have any errorsor warnings '*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching to the stable branch because it is a reported bug. Use

```
flutter channel stable
```

**EDIT**

Damn it this answer got saved as a draft and I closed my laptop. I just realized you had already solved it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator:true).pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`SystemNavigator.pop()` is the recommended way to exit your app.

Answer (score 0):

what I usually use is

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

and it works fine for me. Had a similar issue when adding .pop()